# Can I find sites where I used a certain password?

Tags: google-passwords

Google passwords lets you search by website and then see password for each site. But I want to know, can I search by password and find site(s) that password is used on?

Say I get a phishing email "I know your password is ..." it would be useful to see which site has been hacked/has sold my details.

Comment: That type of message looks like some sort of phishing. Anyway, searching what sites uses certain password looks to me as a big security hole.

Comment: @Rubén Google Passwords and other password managers surely know this...

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @Rubén I mean Google passwords knows what my passwords are. Doesn't it... it can display them on screen

Comment: Just **keep an encrypted local copy in a sheet** and use sheet formulas to find the mentioned password.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

1. Use Google's Password Manager's [**Export** feature](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95606?hl=en&ref_topic=7439541#zippy=%2Cshow-edit-delete-or-export-saved-passwords) to export your login credentials to a CSV file.
2. Open the exported CSV file with any spreadsheet program or (less conveniently) a text editor.
3. Search for the password that you want to check.
4. Securely delete the spreadsheet and the CSV file, or download the CSV file into encrypted storage (like an encrypted Mac Disk Image) in the first place.

**Note:** Google's Password Manager seems to keep only the current passwords, not the history of passwords for your accounts. So this won't let you check past passwords.

Answer (score -1):

Google will only know the leaked passwords, (and only the ones that they know). They don't even know your password that they use on their own site.

Some sites do know your password, you know which bank you are (I don't know why, but banks seem to be particularly bad at this). If they don't know to do password authentication without storing your password, then they are the sort of company that is also more likely to be hacker, or leave a USB-storage-device containing your password and other sensitive data on a train.

And if you get a phishing email, they are trying to invoke a behaviour in you, that will result in compromising your self. If they know your password, then they will not e-mail you saying we know that your password is abcxzy. They won't even tell you that they know it. If they know it, then they want you to be ignorant of this for as long as possible.

<del>Therefore use a password safe/manager</del> (User is already doing this). Use a different password for each site, use passwords of 30 random characters, unless forced to make it weaker by the (banks) security policy. And lock the safe with a good strong pass-phrase, using muli-round encryption (taking about 1/2 a second: fast-enough not to be a pain, and slow-enough to stop an attacker).

Comment: I _am_ using a password manager. That's why I tagged my question with google-passwords.